# Hair particles goes through another object

Tags: mesh, hair

I have a scene with grass that placed inside a room with 2 walls. I added the wind and the turbulence force to make an animation but now my grass (hair particle) goes through the walls of the room. I added collision mod. on room object but it does nothing.
I guessed to add a boolean mod. to cut out certain hair particle when they move through walls but it seems it booleans doesnt work with hair particle...

[image]

Note: "hair dynamics" is deselected in particle settings of the grass (didnt used that feature before, but when i enable it on my grass the grass particles goes in all directions
and i couldnt figure it out how to fix it.

I've found the best ***solution*** for me is to place Force Fields with low maximum distance falloff so when the certain particles touch the walls  it'll be affected by force fields that work as counterweight.
Hours of playing with Hair Dynamics didn't bring results i needed.

Anyway, thanks contributors that come here for help! Really appreciate it.

Comment: You need to activate Hair Dynamics, also if it's not enough play with its parameters like Quality and Distance, if it doesn't work well please share your file (only the useful objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to activate *Hair Dynamics* to have collisions between your hair and your wall, also if it doesn't work well, play with its parameters like collision *Quality* and *Distance*. And make sure that the wall has its normals correctly oriented:

[image]